# How to plot dynamic hourly graph with amchart in php

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to plot line chart with amchart, According to amchart documentation to plot hourly Linegraph this is correct:
  1. "date": "2012-01-01 01"
  2. chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH";
  3.   chart.categoryField = "date";

I followed the same but Still, the x-axis not changed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Brn.png)

```
var lineChartData = [
        {
            "date": "2012-01-01 01",
            "negative": 80,
            "neutral": 40,
            "postitive": 60
        },
        {
            "date": "2012-02-01 02",
            "negative": 72,
            "neutral": 20,
            "postitive": 50
        },

    ];


    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.dataProvider = lineChartData;
        chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
        chart.categoryField = "date";
        chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH";



        // sometimes we need to set margins manually
        // autoMargins should be set to false in order chart to use custom margin values
        chart.autoMargins = false;
        chart.marginRight = 0;
        chart.marginLeft = 30;
        chart.marginBottom = 30;
        chart.marginTop = 40;

        // AXES
        // category                
        var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
        categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
        categoryAxis.minPeriod = "hh"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
        categoryAxis.inside = false;
        categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
        categoryAxis.tickLength = 0;
        categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0.5;
        categoryAxis.fontSize = 9;
        categoryAxis.axisColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
        categoryAxis.color = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";


        // value
        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.dashLength = 2;
        valueAxis.gridColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
        valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.2;
        valueAxis.axisColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
        valueAxis.color = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
        valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.5;
        valueAxis.fontSize = 9;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

        // members
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.type = "smoothedLine";
        graph.valueField = "negative";
        graph.lineColor = "#53d769";
        graph.lineThickness = 3;
        graph.bullet = "round";
        //graph.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
        graph.bulletBorderColor = "#53d769";
        graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
        graph.bulletSize = 6;
        chart.addGraph(graph);

        // orders
        var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph1.type = "smoothedLine";
        graph1.valueField = "neutral";
        graph1.lineColor = "#1c7dfa";
        graph1.lineThickness = 3;
        graph1.bullet = "round";
        //graph1.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
        graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#1c7dfa";
        graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
        graph1.bulletSize = 6;
        chart.addGraph(graph1);

         // orders
        var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
        graph2.valueField = "postitive";
        graph2.lineColor = "#821908";
        graph2.lineThickness = 3;
        graph2.bullet = "round";
        //graph1.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
        graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#821908";
        graph2.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
        graph2.bulletSize = 6;
        chart.addGraph(graph2);


        // CURSOR
        var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
        chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
        chartCursor.categoryBalloonAlpha = 0.2;
        chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0.2;
        chartCursor.cursorColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,.8)';
        chartCursor.categoryBalloonEnabled = false;

        // WRITE
        chart.write("chartdiv");

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data you have isn't hourly, it's monthly (plus one hour, but in amCharts, it's monthly regardless).

AmCharts determines an appropriate period to display your date-based data based on your category axis `minPeriod` and current zoom level/time difference between visible points. Given that your data is over a month apart, it will use a the next highest period formatting to accommodate the visible period formatting. This formatting is defined in the category axis' [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) array, which is set to:

```
 [{
    "period": "fff",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "ss",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "mm",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "hh",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "DD",
    "format": "MMM DD"
  }, {
    "period": "WW",
    "format": "MMM DD"
  }, {
    "period": "MM",
    "format": "MMM DD"
  }, {
    "period": "YYYY",
    "format": "YYYY"
  }]
```

Tweaking MM, WW and DD to include hours in the output will give you the desired labeling, however amCharts will interpret each hour as midnight due to the period setup, so you'll also want to set [`equalSpacing`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#equalSpacing) to true to get the exact hour of each point.

```js
var lineChartData = [{
    "date": "2012-01-01 01",
    "negative": 80,
    "neutral": 40,
    "postitive": 60
  },
  {
    "date": "2012-02-01 02",
    "negative": 72,
    "neutral": 20,
    "postitive": 50
  },

];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
  var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
  chart.dataProvider = lineChartData;
  chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
  chart.categoryField = "date";
  chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH";



  // sometimes we need to set margins manually
  // autoMargins should be set to false in order chart to use custom margin values
  chart.autoMargins = false;
  chart.marginRight = 0;
  chart.marginLeft = 30;
  chart.marginBottom = 30;
  chart.marginTop = 40;

  // AXES
  // category                
  var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
  categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
  categoryAxis.minPeriod = "hh"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
  categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true;
  categoryAxis.inside = false;
  categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
  categoryAxis.tickLength = 0;
  categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0.5;
  categoryAxis.fontSize = 9;
  categoryAxis.axisColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
  categoryAxis.color = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
  categoryAxis.dateFormats = [{
    "period": "fff",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "ss",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "mm",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "hh",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "DD",
    "format": "MMM DD\nHH:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "WW",
    "format": "MMM DD\nHH:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "MM",
    "format": "MMM DD\nHH:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "YYYY",
    "format": "YYYY"
  }];


  // value
  var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
  valueAxis.dashLength = 2;
  valueAxis.gridColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
  valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.2;
  valueAxis.axisColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
  valueAxis.color = "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
  valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.5;
  valueAxis.fontSize = 9;
  chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

  // members
  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.type = "smoothedLine";
  graph.valueField = "negative";
  graph.lineColor = "#53d769";
  graph.lineThickness = 3;
  graph.bullet = "round";
  //graph.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
  graph.bulletBorderColor = "#53d769";
  graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
  graph.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
  graph.bulletSize = 6;
  chart.addGraph(graph);

  // orders
  var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph1.type = "smoothedLine";
  graph1.valueField = "neutral";
  graph1.lineColor = "#1c7dfa";
  graph1.lineThickness = 3;
  graph1.bullet = "round";
  //graph1.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
  graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#1c7dfa";
  graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
  graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
  graph1.bulletSize = 6;
  chart.addGraph(graph1);

  // orders
  var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
  graph2.valueField = "postitive";
  graph2.lineColor = "#821908";
  graph2.lineThickness = 3;
  graph2.bullet = "round";
  //graph1.bulletColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
  graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#821908";
  graph2.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
  graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 3;
  graph2.bulletSize = 6;
  chart.addGraph(graph2);


  // CURSOR
  var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
  chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
  chartCursor.categoryBalloonAlpha = 0.2;
  chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0.2;
  chartCursor.cursorColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,.8)';
  chartCursor.categoryBalloonEnabled = false;

  // WRITE
  chart.write("chartdiv");

});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 275px; background: #0c0c0c;"></div>
```